# Why an "alter table" query takes so long time?

Tags: mysql, database

I'd like to add a field to one table, then run the command like `ALTER Table some_table add some_field varchar(255)`, and it takes more than 1 hour and not finished yet.

This table has around 800k rows and 1.5GB capacity. But anyway I just change the structure, the capacity of the table should take no effect, right?

ENV: MYSQL 5 + Ubuntu 11

Comment: mysql has to rewrite the internal structure of the table, and does this by creating a NEW table file and copying over the data from the original.

Comment: Thanks. Any workaround?

Comment: nope. if you're adding/removing fields, mysql HAS to do the table copy. this is for safety - if there's a problem during the rebuild, it just goes back to the original file. if it was modifing the original in-place and something barfs, now you've got a corrupted + trashed database and lose everything.

Comment: Thanks, learned a lot!

Comment: One more reason to use Postgres, where adding null field is instantaneous.